# Run script in series with input from seq

Tags: bash

I have a script which takes an integer argument. I would like to run this script in series for all integers from, say, 1 to 50. I'm familiar with the `parallel` command, and can accomplish this in a rather roundabout way by forcing it to only run one task at a time:

```
seq 1 50 | parallel -j1 ./myScript.sh {}
```

but I'm assuming there must be a way to do it without using the `parallel` command. What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use `xargs` as in `seq 1 50 | xargs -I {} ./myScript.sh {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach. As an alternative you could use a loop:

```sh
for i in $(seq 1 50); do
  ./myScript.sh "${i}"
done
```

or use xargs:

```sh
seq 1 50 | xargs -n1 ./myScript.sh
```

Comment: Both of these solutions run the script invocations serially.  (not in parallel)

Comment: @WilliamPursell the question asks for serial execution.

Comment: Indeed.  Very odd that it also asks for an alternative to `parallel`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use xargs with -L and -P:

```
 seq 1 50 | xargs -L 1 -P 50 ./myScript.sh
```